String manipulation and conversion
For an exercise, I can take two integers or two strings. If I want integers as input, I need to convert them to strings or if I take strings as input, I need to convert the strings to integers.  When i want to input two strings at once, somehow, they are being concatenated.   If I take integers, when I want to convert using snprintf, the strings are being concatenated again!
When I take strings as input:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    char n[5],m[5];
    scanf("%s %s",n,m);
    printf("%s %s\n",n,m);
}

The input is 12345 56789
but the output is 1234556789 12346
the scanner thinks that "12345 56789" is a whole string.
How is this happening? Didn't I specify that n can only hold 5 char?
If I reduce n[5] to n[1] the output is 156789 56789
When I take integers as input and try to convert using snprintf:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    
    int g,w,cnt=0;
    
    scanf("%d %d",&g,&w);
    
    char n[5], m[5];
    snprintf(n,6,"%d",g);
    snprintf(m,6,"%d",w);
    printf("%s\n",n);
    printf("%s\n",m);
}


If I input 12345 67894
Output is 1234567894 67894.
Same problem as before.
What can I do to fix this issue?

You have not left enough space in the arrays for the null character that marks the end.

Thank you, sir. I didn't know about it's importance. It's working now. @EricPostpischil

Using %s in scanf is dangerous unless you limit it to the number of characters you have place for in the array minus 1 (to leave room for the null terminator), so scanf("%s %s",n,m) should be scanf("%4s %4s",n,m)

There are several issues here:

In order to store a 5 character string, you need a char array of at least 6 elements, because you must keep 1 additional char for the zero termination.
Therefore n and m should be:
char n[6],m[6];


As mentioned by @TedLyngmo using scanf for strings the way you did is unsafe (even after fixing the array sizes), and invokes undefined-behavior if the user enters more than 5 characters per string (because of writing out-of-bounds).
In order to fix it, you should use scanf with a width specifier:

If width specifier is used, matches up to width or until the first whitespace character, whichever appears first.

This is done in the following way:
//------v---v--------
scanf("%5s %5s",n,m);


Good practice dictates always checking the return value from scanf to make sure it succeeded. It returns:

Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned

In your case it should be 2 upon success.


A complete fixed example for your first snippet:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {

    char n[6], m[6];
    if (scanf("%5s %5s", n, m) != 2) {
        // Handle error ...
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s %s\n", n, m);
}

Regarding your second snippet the relevant problematic issues are 1 and 3 above (char array sizes, and checking the return value from scanf).

When defining a char array for storing a string in C, you have to take in account the end of string character (\0) that scanf put into the array implicitly.
So, if you define a char[5] you will be able to store string composed by 4 characters because the last position of array is used for \0.
Change your code in this way:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){   
    char n[6], m[6];
    scanf("%s %s", n, m);
    printf("%s %s\n", n, m);
}

A little improvement of your code, with a check of the return value from scanf, is the following:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char n[6], m[6];
    
    int retCode = scanf("%5s %5s", n, m); // format with max number of chars per array
    if(retCode == 2) { // 2 means that both n and m was successfully populated
       printf("%s %s\n", n, m);
    } else {
       printf("Error occurred. Maybe strings exceeded the array spaces\n");
    }
}

This way you can check if user inserted only one string or if there was some problem during the extraction from stdin into the char arrays.

Thank you. It's working now.  I didn't know about it's importance. I thought it was automatic.   @N3tMaster

and you didn't check the return value of scanf

@TedLyngmo yes you're right but I wanted to give him a fast solution on his code. Anyway, I prefer use fgets with stdin instead scanf

@stup when you use C language you should keep in mind that there is nothing working automatically :D

@N3tMaster The answer is much better now. I removed the redundant EOF check though.
